# How to auto scroll down an iframe 100px every 5 secs?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how can I scroll down an iframe 100px every 5 secs using maybe javascript. I know that there is a `window.scrollTo(x,y);` but how does this change to an iframe?

The iframe is an external page. 
Any possibility of software to download that does this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very easy using a jquery,

Lets say the id of your iframe is `testframe` then the code for it would be

```
$("#testframe").scrollTop(400).scrollLeft(400);
```

Now just wrap it inside an interval and put it inside.

```
var tick=1;
function scrolldown(tick) {
    $("#testframe").scrollTop(tick*100);
}
self.setInterval("scrolldown("+(tick+1)+")",5000);
```

---

<sub>Note: Just a typo</sub>

Comment: This answer is still a bit unclear to me. Can you post a working example of this (e. g., on http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible if you do not have control of the external page's code. browsers prevent this type of thing for security reasons. Its considered [cross-domain scripting](https://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cross-domain+scripting+iframe).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` to do the scrolling every 5 seconds. the scrolling itsself can be done with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page).

Answer (score 0):

Is there an updated version to this method?   Not finding it to actually control the content within the http://time.com">

not showing.  Thats rather puzzling.  So typing iframe inside an iframe makes it go invisible..

Answer (score -1):

If you are building a desktop application (Windows, Linux, not quite sure), I would suggest you to find a component that is the java equivalent of the C# web browser control.

Since this control is loaded in a desktop applicaiton, you have full control over the browser loaded document (e.g. you can manipulate it, without being in a cross domain context).